# angular2 observable, getting undefined in component

Tags: angular

I am new on angular2, I need some help.
I am using below service class.

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
 export class UsersService {
    private _url = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

    constructor(private _http: Http){
    }

    getUsers(){
        return this._http.get(this._url)
            .map(res => res.json());
    }
 }
```

when I am calling above service in below component, I get undefined value.

```
import{Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import{UsersService} from './users.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'users',
    template:'In users',
    //templateUrl: 'app/users.component.html',
    providers: [UsersService] 
})

export class UsersComponent implements OnInit{
users: any[];

    constructor(private _service: UsersService){
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this._service.getUsers()
            .subscribe(result => this.users = result);

        console.log(this.users);
    } 
}
```

But if I tried to log the value in the console in service class, its shows there. any help would be highly appreciable.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Angular 2 HTTP requests return Observables that are run asynchronously from other code. In the `ngOnInit()`, you subscribe to the Observable that `getUsers()` returns, and then outside of the subscription, you have the `console.log()`.

In other words, the `console.log(this.users)` is running before the `getUsers()` has actually completed the HTTP request to actually get the users and before the subscription has assigned them to `this.users`.

Alter `ngOnInit()` like so and you will see the desired result:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this._service.getUsers()
        .subscribe(result => {
            this.users = result;
            console.log(this.users);
        });
}
```

See also:

[RxJS docs on Observables](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html)

[Angular 2 docs on the HTTP client](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#extract-data)

Answer (score 0):

this.user will be available as soon as the observable will be ready, until then, you have to protect your HTML code with *ngIf to avoid exceptions.