# How to show http get from angular 4 response on html

Tags: html, angular, web, get

I am trying to get a data from table with http get method in angular 4. How can I show it on html page?

```
getData(){
  //return this.data;
  return this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/SpringRestExample/get/filedata")
                  .map((response: Response) => 
                      {
                           return response.json();
                   });
}
```

Component.ts

```
getPosts(): void {
console.log("In"+this.service.getData());
this.service.getData()
    .subscribe(
        resultArray => this.data = resultArray,
        error => console.log("Error :: " + error)
    )
    console.log(this.data);
}
```

Here my data shows undefined but get method shows there is object returned. I am not able to get it and show it on html?

Comment: That console.log is *outside the subscription*, of course it's still undefined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular2 observable, getting undefined in component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39172955/angular2-observable-getting-undefined-in-component)

Answer (score 0):

Put your console log method inside the subscribe method.

Answer (score 0):

Your accessing `this.data` before update. Do it as:

```
getPosts(): void {
    console.log("In"+this.service.getData());
    this.service.getData()
        .subscribe(resultArray => {
                this.data = resultArray;
                console.log(this.data);
                // update data source
                this.dataSource.data = this.data;
            },
            error => console.log("Error :: " + error)
        );
}
```

Comment: HI Ashuman, I can see value for data but screen does not show anything as its asynchrounus call. any idea how to handle it?

Comment: can you post HTML?

Comment: No may be due to aynchrounus call

Comment: I want to check how you are accessing it in HTML.

Comment: <mat-table  #table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="consumption-table" matSort>

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="filename">
      <mat-header-cell class="font-weight-table-header"  *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>File Name </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell class="font-weight-table" *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.filename}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container

Comment: you will have to update `dataSource` once data is being received.

Comment: I am doing it bro but html page started loading before data come from web service. how can we stop till we get a data

Comment: you can use `resolver` if you want to load your page after having data only. https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve