# how to access data from a function to parent in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have a class and a function named `getStationDetail` and i want to send a request to server and get the value and save it to `dataFromServer` variable
and i want to return that but when i cal that i get empty array

```
   export class StationService {
      dataFromServer: any = [];
      constructor(private rest: RestService) { }
      getStationsDetail() {
          this.rest.sendRequest('GET', 'station', null).subscribe(
              value => {
                this.dataFromServer = value['Station'];
                // return this.dataFromServer;

              },
          );
          return this.dataFromServer;
      }
    }
```

and i cal it

```
export class StationComponent implements OnInit(){
    mm: any;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.mm = this._stationService.getStationsDetail().subscribe();
        console.log(this.mm);
    }
}
```

but map not worked? how to cal subscribe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular2 observable, getting undefined in component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39172955/angular2-observable-getting-undefined-in-component)

Comment: Or many other similar questions; the request is *asynchronous*, that's why you need to subscribe and why the value is only available *in the callback*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a request is sent to server then cursor doesn't stop to execute next lines of codes if we want some operations after receiving the response from server then we use observables and do these methods in subscribe(). so for examples:

```
 ngOnInit() {
  this._stationService.getStationsDetail()
  .subscribe(stationDetails => {
  console.log('Response array:' , stationDetails);
  });}
```

Comment: i have used that but it tslint sends Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void

Comment: just remove "this.mm = ="